# XCUI Test Results on Jenkins

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, xcuitest

We have XCUItests running on the daily jenkins build. The results as to how many tests passed or failed shows up in the console log. These do not give an idea of where the test failed or why. Is there a way to display the XCUI test results on the jenkins job with pass/fail status and linked screenshots?

Comment: Hi Madonna, I think you forgot the screenshots.

Comment: I actually meant the screenshots that go with a test fail. Sorry about the mis-communication. Usually when a test fails, XCode takes a screenshot which it does store, so my question was on how to get Jenkins to show the test status together with pass/fail status and screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

Any of the following libraries will help in getting html reports with screenshots

1. xcpretty
2. XCTestHTMLReport

Html reports along with the screenshots can be archived from the jenkins' post build action

Comment: Thanks Prakash, will try out the 2nd. Currently I use xcpretty but see no way to pull in screenshots. The -screenshots command did not work.

Comment: I was not able to get this working. Is there a git repo that you can direct me to - also how can I dispay this screenshot on test failure in the jenkins job result. (As of now, I use this command to display junit results on the jenkins job -> xcpretty --simple -r junit).

Comment: After the test is run, execute the following command

`xchtmlreport -r "path/to/test-results"`

This will create "path/to/test-results/index.html" which is our report file along with screenshots from "path/to/test-results/1_Test/Attachments/"